# Searching a good Ultrabook for work

Tags: laptop, processor, battery-life

I'm looking for a Ultrabook with this characteristics:

**Essential**

- 8th or 7th generation of CPU. (i5, i7 or amd)
- Not more than 13"/14" of screen size.
- Very important the weight... i need to travel with him.
- 6 GB of ram or more.
- Not more of 1200-1300€.

These features are essential because I need this ultrabook to work, I do not need it for games, so the graphics card is not important for me, I am a developer and I need good hardware to work with Virtualbox, Eclipse, VisualCode, IntelliJ and similar...

**Others**

- Good battery life, but i don't care about have more than 9 hours, with 6 or more it's okay.
- I don't' want a Microsoft surface or similar products.
- I don't need a touch screen.
- In general, good opinions in internet about the model.

Some reference models: Asus Zenbook 3, Dell Xps 13, some Thinkpad... I'm looking for a good argumentation for help me to decide abaout all Ultrabook offers and this argumentes based in a experience working with the model.

Comment: Hi, I noticed to listed your currency as '€'. I can possibly give you a purchase recommendation that could ship to you as fast as you can buy it if you specify your locale.

Comment: @BennettYeo the currency isn't important, if u will do a recommendation you can put it in an answer. I'll ty.

Comment: the currency is less important that than the location where you would want this system to ship to. Price, availability, and therefore the best recommendation for you, is highly dependent on location. Where in the EU/UK would you like this laptop to ship to?